# Why do I get 'MySQL server has gone away' after running a Telegram bot for some hours?

Tags: python, mysql, django, mysql-python

I'm building a Django (ver. 3.0.5) app that uses `mysqlclient` (ver. 2.0.3) as the DB backend. Additionally, I've written a Django command that runs a bot written using the [python-telegram-bot](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot) API, so the mission of this bot is to run indefinitely, as it has to answer to commands anytime.

Problem is that approximately 24hrs. after running the bot (not necessarily being idle all the time), I get a `django.db.utils.OperationalError: (2006, 'MySQL server has gone away')` exception after running any command.

I'm absolutely sure the MySQL server has been running all the time and is still running at the time I get this exception. The MySQL server version is `5.7.35`.

My assumption is that some MySQL threads get aged out and get closed, so after reusing them they won't get renewed.

Has anyone bumped into this situation and knows how to solve it?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/django/gip/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/telegram/ext/dispatcher.py", line 555, in process_update
    handler.handle_update(update, self, check, context)
  File "/opt/django/gip/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/telegram/ext/handler.py", line 198, in handle_update
    return self.callback(update, context)
  File "/opt/django/gip/gip/hospital/gipcrbot.py", line 114, in ayuda
    perfil = get_permiso_efectivo(update.message.from_user.id)
  File "/opt/django/gip/gip/hospital/telegram/funciones.py", line 33, in get_permiso_efectivo
    u = Telegram.objects.get(idtelegram=userid)
  File "/opt/django/gip/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/django/gip/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 411, in get
    num = len(clone)
  File "/opt/django/gip/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 258, in __len__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "/opt/django/gip/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1261, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
  File "/opt/django/gip/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 57, in __iter__
    results = compiler.execute_sql(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch, chunk_size=self.chunk_size)
  File "/opt/django/gip/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1151, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/opt/django/gip/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 100, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "/opt/django/gip/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 68, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "/opt/django/gip/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 77, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "/opt/django/gip/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 86, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/opt/django/gip/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/opt/django/gip/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 86, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/opt/django/gip/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 74, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
  File "/opt/django/gip/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 206, in execute
    res = self._query(query)
  File "/opt/django/gip/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 319, in _query
    db.query(q)
  File "/opt/django/gip/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 259, in query
    _mysql.connection.query(self, query)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (2006, 'MySQL server has gone away')
```

### **Things I have tried**

I already tried changing the Django settings.py file so I set an explicit value for `CONN_MAX_AGE`, and I also set a value for the MySQL client `wait_timeout` parameter, being `CONN_MAX_AGE` lower than `wait_timeout`.

**settings.py**:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'read_default_file': '/opt/django/gip/gip/gip/my.cnf',
        },
        'CONN_MAX_AGE': 3600,
    }
}
```

**my.cnf**:

```
[client]
...
wait_timeout = 28800
```

Unfortunately, the behavior is exactly the same: I get an exception approximately 24hrs. after running the bot.

---

Setting `CONN_MAX_AGE` to `None` won't make any difference either.

---

I installed the `mysql-server-has-gone-away` python package as proposed by @r-marolahy, but it won't make a difference either. After nearly 24hours after running it the "gone away" message shows again.

---

I also tried the approach of closing old connections:

```
from django.db import close_old_connections

try:
    #do your long running operation here
except django.db.utils.OperationalError:
    close_old_connections()
    #do your long running operation here
```

Still getting the same result.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/gone-away.html

Comment: Are you using `POLLING` method?

Comment: @EgorWexler if you mean the `python-telegram-bot` library, then yes, I use the polling method.

Comment: I suggest switching to `WEBHOOK`. Polling might cause some overloads or the mentioned `long` connections. I am using `python-telegram-bot` since April in production with webhook and didn't have a single issue since then

Comment: @EgorWexler is your database backend also MySQL?

Comment: @nKn, yes, exactly MySQL. I started with `polling` but there were a lot of other problems (it also used to stop polling after certain amount of time) so when switched to webhook everything became smooth

Comment: Well, this question currently has a bounty on it so I cannot mark it as a duplicate, so a comment it is: [Why am I getting the “MySQL server has gone away” exception in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59773675/why-am-i-getting-the-mysql-server-has-gone-away-exception-in-django) Also a management command is not ideal for long running tasks, look for some other solutions. You get the error because Django closes the connections only at each request a management command running forever of course doesn't get any requests, etc. so no connection management occurs.

Comment: try setting `CONN_MAX_AGE` to 0, so DB connection will be closed on every request, see if that resolves the problem, if it does, use binary search to find the optimal time out between 0 and 3600.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up scheduling a DB query every X hours (in this case, 6h) in the bot. The `python-telegram-bot` has a class called [JobQueue](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.ext.jobqueue.html) which has a method called `run_repeating`. This will run a task every *n* seconds. So I declared:

```
def check_db(context):
    # Do the code for running "SELECT 1" in the DB
    return

updater.job_queue.run_repeating(check_db, interval=21600, first=21600)
```

After this change I haven't had the same problem again.

---

Also, calling the mostly undocumented `close_if_unusable_or_obsolete()` Django method from time to time works as well in my case.

```
from django.db import connection

connection.close_if_unusable_or_obsolete()
```

Answer (score 5):

This error happened to django when MySQL closed the connection because of the server timed out. To enable persistent connections, set `CONN_MAX_AGE` to a positive integer of seconds or set it to `None` for unlimited persistent connections ([source](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/databases/#s-persistent-connections)).

**Update1:**
If the proposed solution above didn't work, you may want to try [mysql-server-has-gone-away](https://pypi.org/project/mysql-server-has-gone-away/) package. I haven't tried it yet but it might help in this situation.

**Update2:** another attempt is to try to use `try/except` statement to catch this `OperationalError` and reset the connection with `close_old_connections`.

```
from django.db import close_old_connections

try:
    #do your long running operation here
except django.db.utils.OperationalError:
    close_old_connections()
    #do your long running operation here
```

**update3:** as described [here](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/stable/topics/databases.html)

> The Django ORM is a synchronous piece of code, and so if you want to access it from asynchronous code you need to do special handling to make sure its connections are closed properly.

However, it seams that Django ORM uses `asgiref.sync.sync_to_async` adapter which works only until MySQL closed the connection. In this case using `channels.db.database_sync_to_async` (which is `SyncToAsync` version that cleans up old database connections when it exits) might solve this issue.

You can use it like the following ([source](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/stable/topics/databases.html#database-sync-to-async)):

```
from channels.db import database_sync_to_async

async def connect(self):
    self.username = await database_sync_to_async(self.get_name)()

def get_name(self):
    return User.objects.all()[0].name
```

or use it as a decorator:

```
@database_sync_to_async
def get_name(self):
    return User.objects.all()[0].name
```

Make sure to follow the installation instruction [here](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/stable/installation.html) first.

Comment: Unfortunately, I tried setting `MAX_CONN_AGE` to `3600` and in mysql client configuration `wait_timeout` to `28800` and this is still happening.

Comment: Just changed it. We'll see in 24 hrs.

Comment: Did you restart your mysql service after this change? If not it didn't applied yet.

Comment: Sure. Any change has been applied restarting the bot.

Comment: Unfortunately, setting `MAX_CONN_AGE` to `None` did not the trick either, the Exception shows up again.

Comment: I just added an update. Give it a try and let me know if it works.

Comment: Just changed it and restarted the bot. We'll see in 24 hrs.

Comment: Using the `mysql-server-has-gone-away` package seems to have done the trick. I'll keep watching for some days and see if it works all the time. Thanks.

Comment: It's my pleasure

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't work... I thought it took more time to timeout and also I had a misconfigured parameter for MySQL, so yesterday I restarted it. Today, nearly 1 day after, it shows the gone away message again.

Comment: Sorry about that. I just added an update, check it out and let me know.

Comment: Also tried this approach, same result. I wonder if there's something more going on here...

Comment: I suspect the error is from what I described in the update. You may want to give it a try again.

Answer (score 0):

This is usually because of server side [wait_timeout](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_wait_timeout). Server is closing connection after wait_timeout seconds of inactivity.
You should either increase timeout:

```
SET SESSION wait_timeout = ...
```

Or deal with this sort of error and reconnect and retry when it happens.

Another option is to ping server with query (like `select 1`) in regular intervals (`wait_timeout - 1`)

Comment: I'd prefer not increasing the timeout setting since that won't solve the problem, the bot is meant to be running all time, so it would just pospone the exception. I'm also unsure the `select 1` option  would work, since the bot is not necessarily idle all the 24hrs., I've been working with it yesterday after being about 18hrs idle. and it worked. However, I tried to run it today (approx. 12 hours since the last time I entered last command) and it threw the exception.

Comment: I agree that increasing timeout may not be a good idea (large timeouts may lead to network issues if there nat etc..)
I'm not sure whether it is possible to plug automatic reconnection function into django db layer.
But what you can do is to make "preflight" query. For example if before starting any activity you see that last activity was more than N seconds ago, you could issue such a query (`select 1` or smth) eventually handle "gone away" exception and reinitialize database connection and then proceed to your app logic.

Answer (score 0):

The connection will break for any of a number of reasons, not just timeouts.
So, simply plan for it breaking.

Plan A (most robust solution):

Whenever running a query, check for errors and have code to reconnect and rerun the query (or transaction).

Plan B (risky for transactions):

Turn on auto-reconnect.  This is *bad* if you ever use multi-statement transactions.  Auto-reconnect in the middle of a transaction can lead to a corrupt dataset (by violating the semantics of a "transaction".)  This is because the first part of the transaction is `ROLLBACK'd` (due to the disconnect) and the rest is `COMMITted`.

Plan C (straight-forward):

Connect when a message comes in; do your work; then disconnect.  That is, be disconnected most of the time.  This approach is necessary if you could have lots of clients connecting (but rarely doing anything).

Plan D (not worth considering):

Increase various timeouts.  Why bother solving one problem (low timeout) when other other problems go unsolved (network hiccup).

My preference?  C is easy and nearly always sufficient.  A takes more code, but is "best".  Both C and A is possibly even better.

Comment: Actually, `Plan C` is how Django should be working by default, as per the documentation, regarding `CONN_MAX_AGE`: `The default value is 0, preserving the historical behavior of closing the database connection at the end of each request.`. I'd rather not touch any timeouts, since this is just postponing the problem, the bot is meant to be running all the time. Django should handle any database connection as you described `Plan C`, that's why I don't understand why these timeouts still happen.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why that happen is because the `close_old_connection` function.

So, what you can try to do is to add the call to close old connection before interacting with db:

**Example Code:**

```py
from django.db import close_old_connections
close_old_connections()
# do some db actions, it will reconnect db
```

Please let me know if it not resolve your issue.

Comment: As I see in the documentation, Django already uses this method to close any connections past their lifetime and renew it for any new request. I guess this is not the problem here, since Django itself is already using this method and the error is still happening.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too.
The `(2006, 'MySQL server has gone away')` can happen for various reasons, among:

- Too long requests

Solution is to fine tune MySQL / MariaDB to allow bigger requests:

In `/etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/50-server.cnf`

```
[mysqld]
...
max_allowed_packet=128M
innodb_log_file_size = 128M # Fix kopano-server: SQL [00000088] info: MySQL server has gone away. Reconnecting, see https://jira.kopano.io/browse/KC-1053
```

- No interaction with the client for a couple of hours

You can use whatever other solutions are posted here.
Solution can be to set the timeout to something very big (80 hours in my setup)

In `/etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/50-server.cnf`

```
[mysqld]
...
wait_timeout = 288000 # Increase timeout to 80h before Mysql server will also go away
```

Comment: The first one isn't the reason in this case. I already tried the second one and made no difference.

Answer (score 0):

The solution for **Django >= 4.1** to enable [persistent connections](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/databases/#persistent-database-connections) with [health-checks](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#conn-max-age)

```
DATABASES = {
   'default': {
       'CONN_HEALTH_CHECKS': True,
       'CONN_MAX_AGE': 60,  # <= Mysql `interactive_timeout`/`wait_timeout`  
   }
}
```

After that for each db request Django will ping database to check if connection usable and if not Django will close connection