# Django 4.0.4 doesn't reconnect to MySQL transparently?

Tags: mysql, django

I've read this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59773675/why-am-i-getting-the-mysql-server-has-gone-away-exception-in-django), but apparently the behaviour is still vague.
I've a long running process which makes a round each second. During the round I make a request to the DB (select type), then have some processing, eventually saving objects.
If the connection is broken for some reason, first of all I get this exception:

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (2013, 'Lost connection to server during query')
```

I then do nothing about the connection (no closing, no pinging), and on the next round I get this:

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (2006, 'Server has gone away')
```

The situation repeats ad infinitum, nothing rectifies itself.

Therefore the question: the rumours of django reconnecting itself are not true? I've MAX_CONN_AGE set to 0, and MySQL wait_timeout is default 28800 (in any case since I have a DB request each second, I should never experience that timeout). I would expect django reestablishing the connection if the server is gone, why it's not happening?